# Why in WSO2 ESB I can't create a new property that is the concatenation of another property and a fixed string? I obtain null as result

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am pretty new in **WSO2 ESB** and I have the following problem. I have a simple POST API that receives a JSON payload. I correctly extract the JSON content into properties.

Then I have to create a new property containing the content of one of the previous properties (retrieved from the JSON document) and I have to concatenatet a fixed string to its content.

So my API is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/meteo" name="meteo_data_population_insert" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST" protocol="http" uri-template="/forecast">
        <inSequence>
            <log level="full"/>
            <log description="Log" level="custom">
                <property name="message" value="meteo_data_population_insert START !!!"/>
            </log>

            <property expression="json-eval($.forecast_date)" name="forecast_date" scope="default" type="STRING"/>

            <property expression="json-eval($.morning.weather.min_temp)" name="morning_min_temp" scope="default" type="STRING"/>


            <log level="custom">
                <property expression="$ctx:forecast_date" name="forecast_date"/>
            </log>
            <log level="custom">
                <property expression="$ctx:morning_min_temp" name="morning_min_temp"/>
            </log>

            <property name="forecast_date_CONCAT" expression="fn:concat($ctx:forecast_date, '_morning')" scope="operation" type="STRING"/>
            <log level="custom">
                <property expression="$ctx:forecast_date_CONCAT" name="forecast_date_CONCAT"/>
            </log>


        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

As you can see I am retrieving from the JSON payload the value of the **forecast_date** field:

```
<property expression="json-eval($.forecast_date)" name="forecast_date" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

It works fine (I can see it into the log), then I want to create a new property that start with the content of this **forecast_date** and concatenate to it the **_morning** string.

So I tried to do in this way:

```
<property name="forecast_date_CONCAT" expression="fn:concat($ctx:forecast_date, '_morning')" scope="operation" type="STRING"/>
<log level="custom">
    <property expression="$ctx:forecast_date_CONCAT" name="forecast_date_CONCAT"/>
</log>
```

The problem is that in the log I obtain this result:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-03-08 16:03:46,882]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  message = meteo_data_population_insert START !!! {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-03-08 16:03:46,883]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  forecast_date = 2018-03-14 {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-03-08 16:03:46,883]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  morning_min_temp = 24 {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-03-08 16:03:46,884]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  forecast_date_CONCAT = null {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
```

So as you can see I am correctly retrieving the **forecast_date** value but when I try to create the new **forecast_date_CONCAT** property concatenating this value with the **_morning string** it doesn't work and I obtain **null** as value of this new propery.

Why? What is wrong in my code? What am I missing? How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Solve by myself in this way:

```
<property expression="fn:concat(get-property('forecast_date'), '_morning')" name="forecast_date_CONCAT" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
<log level="custom">
    <property expression="$ctx:forecast_date_CONCAT" name="forecast_date_CONCAT"/>
</log>
```

Comment: one tip: you can enable in 'configure->logging' the 'mediators.builtin.PropertyMediator' so you can see directly what the values are of the properties after setting. At first glance I do not see anything wrong with initial code though :)